# Vue 3 Vue-router 4 Composition API - Calling router.push outside of component not working

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-router4

In my Vue 3 project, i use the composition API of Vue and i have axios defined as a plugin in `plugins/axios.js` like this:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
import { useErrorStore } from "../stores/error";

axios.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
      return response;
    },
    (error) => {
      const errorStore = useErrorStore();
      errorStore.state.errors.push(error.response.data.detail);
      if (parseInt(error.response.status) == 422) {
        const router = useRouter();
        router.push({
          name: "login",
        });
      }
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );
export default axios;
```

**ANTICIPATED BEHAVIOR:**
When the API call returns a 422 status, meaning the access token is invalid/ expired, the user shall be redirected to the login page.

**PROBLEM:**
`router.push` does not work, i am not redirected when the error occurs. And i am not getting any error message on the console either.

On the other hand, the `errorStore` as defined and accessed in the error case works just fine.

**QUESTION:**
How can i redirect the user to another route from within the custom axios plugin file?
Alternatively, is there a better/ more common way to achieve this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's useRouter that doesn't work, don't use it in random places, import router directly

Comment: Thank you! using `import router from "../router"`solved the issue.

Comment: @EstusFlask when you say "random places", when is it advised to use `router` vs. `useRouter` ?

Comment: Vue composables are primarily intended to be used directly in component setup, any other usage relies on composable implementation and needs to be confirmed. Things like useRouter use provide/inject to get an instance from a value that was provided to app plugin, they depend on component hierarchy and are limited to components